# How to add comments against files in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have a document library with multiple files.

Is there an out-of-the-box way to add comments against files in a document library?

Comment: Comments as like inside word document? or Metadata of document?

Comment: Outside so that all users can comment on it and interact.. Is there an out-of-the-box way for such a idea?

Answer (score 0):

6 ways to add comments to documents in SharePoint for your reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-to-add-comments-to-documents-in-sharepoint/